# puma: puma.sock No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, ansible, puma

I used ansible script for server setup:

[playbook.yml](https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/ea6314734413d9942ce339960c204b50)

[Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/95ab89ce88ddd6e7952cbbd751dd1214)

And when I deployed my application to server, I see this in nginx/error.log:

```
2016/09/30 20:43:07 [crit] 1352#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/deploy/applications/spa_backend/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/applications/spa_backend/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/",
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capfile:

`require 'capistrano/puma'`

it helped me

Comment: What is "Capfile"? Don't know if this will help me or not because I don't know the context.